# optional nargs variable in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

How I can do conditional loop with argparse with variable nargs? So, basically, it should run with or without argument.
I am trying:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="output parser")
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("--dos", help="get DOSCAR for plot",
                   nargs="?", metavar=("int"))
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.dos:    
    if len(args.dos) > 1:
        chosen = int(args.dos[0])
        chdos = "at_dos"+args.dos[0]+".dat"
    else:
        chosen = None

    inpt = "DOSY"
    print(chosen)
    print(inpt)
```

Now, if I have variable, then its printing some value, wrong but some value:

```
$python3 vasp.py --dos 111
111
None   # IT SHOULDN'T BE NONE
DOSY
```

but nothing without argument.

I have also tried with the normal sys.argv, as:

```
def get_dos():
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        chosen = int(sys.argv[2])
        chdos = "at_dos"+sys.argv[2]+".dat"
    else:
        chosen = None
    inpt = "DOSCAR"
    print(sys.argv)

    print(args.dos)
    print(chosen)
    print(inpt)
```

in this case, when option is present, its giving correct result:

```
python3 vasp.py --dos 12
['vasp.py', '--dos', '12']
12
12
DOSCAR
```

but again, nothing without option:

```
$python3 vasp.py --dos
```

I have tried with hpaulj's suggestion. It gives:

```
$python3 tt.py --dos 12
Namespace(dos='12')
1
DOSY
```

and without argument, its still not printing anything.

Comment: I don't get that `None` when I run it and fix the invalid syntax. What version of Python are you using? I've tried both 3.5.1 and 2.7.11 and it works in both versions. You need a [mcve].

Comment: Also, I don't think `len(args.dos) > 1` does what you think it does. It checks if you've entered a number with more than 1 digit.

Comment: Did you try `print(args)` to see directly what was parsed?

Comment: You now need a test that can handle the string '12', not a list or number.  A string.

Comment: What is is supposed to do with just `--dos` and without it at all?

Comment: @hpaulj, from the minimal example at the top, it should print the values. So, without any argument of --dos, i should have `chosen=None`, and `str DOSY` printed. With a argument, say, `--dos 111`, i should have `chosen=111`, and str `DOSY`.  The argument od --dos is an integer, and I dont want to split it.

Comment: Does my last edit produce the kind of values that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all the people who replied, and specially @hpaulj. But none of them really solve my problem. So, I took other way. I am posting this here for completeness.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="output parser")
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("--dos", help="get DOSCAR for plot",action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("-n", help="Showing last n line",
                    metavar='integer', type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.dos:
    if args.n:
        chosen = int(args.n)
        chdos = "at_dos"+str(args.n)+".dat"
    else:
        chosen = None
    inpt = "DOSY"
    print(inpt)
    print(chosen)
```

which yields expected results properly:

```
$python3 tt.py --dos
DOSY
None

$python3 tt.py --dos -n 222
DOSY
222
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying your parser in a Ipython session:

```
In [1004]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()    
In [1005]: parser.add_argument('--dos', nargs='?')

In [1007]: parser.parse_args('--dos 111'.split())
Out[1007]: Namespace(dos='111')
```

In this case `args.dos` will be the string '111', with `len` 3, and `int(args.dos[0])` the number 1.  The same happens in you leave `nargs` blank (default None).

With `nargs='?'` I can also use the flag without an argument, in which case the value is the default `None`.

```
In [1013]: parser.parse_args('--dos'.split())
Out[1013]: Namespace(dos=None)
```

`nargs=`?`is most useful with a`const`, which gives a convenient 3 way action.  I can add`type=int` to convert the string, if any to integer.

```
In [1015]: parser.add_argument('--dos', nargs='?', type=int,
   default=None, const=123)

In [1016]: parser.parse_args([]) # not used
Out[1016]: Namespace(dos=None)

In [1017]: parser.parse_args('--dos'.split())  # without argument
Out[1017]: Namespace(dos=123)

In [1018]: parser.parse_args('--dos 456'.split())  # with argument
Out[1018]: Namespace(dos=456)
```

Other `nargs`, like 1, '*' and '+' give you a list, which you can check for length etc.

====================

In your `argv` testing

```
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    chosen = int(sys.argv[2])
    chdos = "at_dos"+sys.argv[2]+".dat"
```

`sys.argv` is a list, so the len counts if there are enough elements to apply the `sys.argv[2]` step.

This does not work because `args.dos` is a single string, not a list.

```
if len(args.dos) > 1:
    chosen = int(args.dos[0])
    chdos = "at_dos"+args.dos[0]+".dat"
```

`len(args.dos)` is then the number of characters in the string, and `args.dos[0]` is the first character.

============

If I define:

```
def get_dos(argv=None):
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--dos', type=int, nargs='?')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    chosen = args.dos
    if chosen is not None:
        chdos = 'at_dos%s.dat'%chosen
    else:
        chdos = ''
    return chosen, chdos
```

these tests produce values which I think match your needs:

```
In [1042]: get_dos([])
Out[1042]: (None, '')

In [1043]: get_dos(['--dos'])
Out[1043]: (None, '')

In [1044]: get_dos(['--dos','123'])
Out[1044]: (123, 'at_dos123.dat')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace nargs = "?" with nargs = "*". Setting nargs to "?" means there will be 1 optional argument. What you want is a list of optional arguments, which is "*". Like so.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="output parser")
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("--dos", help="get DOSCAR for plot",
               nargs="*", metavar=("int"))
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.dos:    
    if len(args.dos) > 1:
        chosen = int(args.dos[0])
        chdos = "at_dos"+args.dos[0]+".dat"
    else:
        chosen = None

    inpt = "DOSY"
    print(chosen)
    print(inpt)
```

Comment: I have already tried nargs = "*". Have you checked the code? its giving same problem.